# How to check static IP address using Prometheus & Blackbox exporter

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I would like to check every **30s** whether it is possible to connect to the static IP address **10.0.0.5** on port **80**. Unfortunately I cannot find any valid example. I assume it should look something like the following snippet:

```
  http_2xx:
    prober: http
    timeout: 30s
    http:
      valid_http_versions: ["HTTP/1.1", "HTTP/2"]
      preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4"
      endpoint: "10.0.0.5"
```

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: 1. This question is offtopic for SO. And I'm not sure in it's current state it will be accepted by [su].

Comment: 2. I recommend reading [this](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration) and next after it block of readme closely. IMO, its rather clear in what needs to be done, and if not asking more detailed question.

Comment: If you don't have anything useful to write, don't write anything pls...